# PATH function in Power Query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I'm trying to create multiple hierarchy columns in Power Query based on a PATH column.

My data looks like the following, where:

1. *Parent Path* has multiple nested parent IDs,
2. All levels of hierarchy are in the same *Department ID* column (even if they are level 1, 2 or 3). In the following case, HR Strategy is part of HR Department:

| Department ID | Department Name | Parent ID | Parent Path |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 211 | HR Strategy | 209 | 209｜211 |
| 209 | HR Department | 209 | 209 |

The output I want is the following:

| Department ID | Department Name | Parent ID | Parent Path | Level 1 Hier. | Level 2 Hier. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 211 | HR Strategy | 209 | 209｜211 | HR Department | HR Strategy |

... and so on, where it extracts unit names onto the corresponding rows by ID.

I've looked into the DAX PATH expression, but it seems to be used for generating such PATH columns.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in your table only Department ID, Department Name and Parent ID.

Then add the following columns=

```
EntityPath = PATH ( 'Table'[Department ID], 'Table'[Parent ID])

Depth = PATHLENGTH ( 'Table'[EntityPath] )

Level 1 Hier. = 
VAR LevelNumber = 1
VAR LevelKey = PATHITEM ( 'Table'[EntityPath], LevelNumber, INTEGER )
VAR LevelName = LOOKUPVALUE ('Table'[Department Name],'Table'[Department ID],LevelKey)
VAR Result = LevelName
RETURN
Result

Level 2 Hier. = 
VAR LevelNumber = 2
VAR LevelKey = PATHITEM ( 'Table'[EntityPath], LevelNumber, INTEGER )
VAR LevelName = LOOKUPVALUE ('Table'[Department Name],'Table'[Department ID],LevelKey)
VAR Result = LevelName
RETURN
Result
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Didn't figure out how to do it in Power Query, but there's a function named PATHITEM in DAX, which I used to create a new column:

```
Level 1 Hier. = 
LOOKUPVALUE(
    Department_Table[Department Name],
    Department_Table[Department ID],
        PATHITEM(
            Department_Table[Parent Path],
            1,
            TEXT
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let
  Source = SomeTable,
    #"Added custom - path" = Table.AddColumn(Source, 
                                      "Path", 
                                      each let mytable=Source,
                                                p="parent_id_col",
                                                c="child_id_col", 
                                                r="child_title_col" 
                                            in
                                            let mylist={Record.Field(_,r)} & List.Generate(()=>[x=0, y=Record.Field(_,p), w=1, phi=""],
                                                                                            each [w] > 0,
                                                                                            each [z=[y], 
                                                                                                    x=Table.Column(Table.SelectRows(mytable,each Record.Field(_,c)=z),p),
                                                                                                    y=x{0},
                                                                                                    w=List.Count(x),
                                                                                                    phi=Table.Column(Table.SelectRows(mytable,each Record.Field(_,c)=z),r){0}],
                                                                                            each [phi])
                                            in
                                                Text.Combine(List.Reverse(List.RemoveItems(List.Transform(mylist,each Text.From(_)),
                                                                                           {null,""}
                                                                                           )
                                                                        ),
                                                            "|")),
  
in
  #"Added custom - path"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).